# How to find the second-to-last occurrence of a character within a string?

Tags: php, string

If possible, using only standard PHP functions like substr(), strrpos(), strpos(), etc.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

First, find the last position:

```
$last = strrpos($haystack, $needle);
if ($last === false) {
  return false;
}
```

From there, find the 2nd last:

```
$next_to_last = strrpos($haystack, $needle, $last - strlen($haystack) - 1);
```

Comment: Bah, didn't test this fully. That should do it.

Answer (score 10):

General solution for any number of backwards steps:

```
function strrpos_count($haystack, $needle, $count)
{
    if($count <= 0)
        return false;

    $len = strlen($haystack);
    $pos = $len;

    for($i = 0; $i < $count && $pos; $i++)
        $pos = strrpos($haystack, $needle, $pos - $len - 1);

    return $pos;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With `strpos`:

```
$pos = -1; $last = null; $secondLast = null;
while (($pos = strpos($haystack, $needle, $pos+1)) !== false) {
    $secondLast = $last;
    $last = $pos;
}
if (!is_null($secondLast)) {
    echo 'second last occured on '.$secondLast;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Search for a regexp (plz correct me if I'm wrong, and how to write it in PHP):

```
    r'x[^x]*x[^x]*$'.replace('x',your_char)
```

Comment: Read the question again; I don't think the OP is permitted to use regexes.

Comment: This is exactly what I was after, though, so tyvm! I won't upvote since it doesn't exactly answer the OP's question, but I'm glad you posted your answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this can be done with strrpos because the position start does not 
work in the way you would expect.

There is afaik not any obvious way, but this function should do it. (Not really tested, but I think it work).

```
    /** Return the position of the second last needle in haystack or false if nothing is found. I really hate functions with return types that depend on their input, but this function is made to look like the similary php functions (strpos, strrpos and so on) */

// Needle must be a char. If you want it to be a string instead, just substr
// length of needle instead of 1 in this example.
    function findSecondLastChar($needle,$haystack) {
      $found=0;
      for($pos=strlen($haystack)-1;$pos>=0;$pos--) {
        if(substr($haystack,$pos,1)==$needle) {
          if($found++ == 1)
            return $pos;
        }
      }
       // If we reach this, nothing were found
       return false;
    }
```

Comment: Martin, I agree strrpos is  very unintuitive, but I finally got it to work.  See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can can use two lots of strrpos with a negative offset to do the trick:

```
$str = 'foo fighters fight foo';    
$p0 = strrpos($str,' '); // get position o last space
$os = -strlen($str)+$p0-1; // negative search offset
$p1 = strrpos($str,' ',$os); // position of the second last space
echo '"'.substr($str,$p1).'"'; // result
```