# php, second last comma in a string to break string, or regex

Tags: php, regex, string

I'm trying to find a way to break a string at the second last comma, for example:

`piece 1, piece 2, piece 3, piece 4, piece 5, piece 6, piece 7` should be 2 parts:

`piece 1, piece 2, piece 3, piece 4, piece 5` and

`piece 6, piece 7`

and

`piece 1, piece 2, piece 3, piece 4, piece 5` should be:

`piece 1, piece 2, piece 3` and

`piece 4, piece 5`

Is there a string manipulation to search the string for a character and identify the position of the second last instance of that character?

I thought about exploding the string by `,` then gluing the last 2 to make part 2, and gluing however many first ones (varies) to make part 1, but I think that might be overkill. Any string manipulations for this?

Comment: similair question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/998932/how-to-find-the-second-to-last-occurrence-of-a-character-within-a-string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`strrpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrchr.php) to find the position of the last comma.

Use `strrpos` with the last position as the *offset* to find the 2nd last comma.

Break the string with `substr`.

Answer (score 2):

why do you think its overkill using [array_splice()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)?

```
$string="piece 1, piece 2, piece 3, piece 4, piece 5, piece 6, piece 7";
$s = explode(",",$string);
$t=array_slice($s, 0,-2);
$e=array_slice($s,-2);
print_r($t);
print_r($e);
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though I agree with codaddict that regular expressions probably isn't really needed, heres more:

For the first n-2 items, replace `',[^,]+,[^,]+$'` with '' in the string

For for last 2 items, find the match of `'[^,]+,[^,]+$'` in the string

Answer (score 0):

Regex is a overkill here, you can easily use strpos and substr as mentioned by Kenny. But here is a regex basesd solution:

```
if(preg_match('{^(.*),(.*?),(.*?)$}',$input,$matches)) {
  $part1 = $matches[1];
  $part2 = $matches[2].','.$matches[3];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo preg_replace('~,\s*(?=[^,]*,[^,]*$)~', ",\n", $str)
```

regular expressions is a tool specifically designed for problems like this, and there's no single reason not to use them. strpos() and friends are just so stupid and verbose...

Comment: or $parts = preg_split('~,\s*(?=[^,]*,[^,]*$)~', $str);, depending on what OP means with 'break a string'